# Vue and Laravel: Are the Vue components even necessary if everything is being read of a bundled file?

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am building an an app inside a Laravel project using Vue components.  The blade layout reads off of the bundled app.js so I was wondering when using frameworks like Vue and React, are the files even necessary other than just being there for the bundle process?  Like what I had actually removed the .vue files I have (components) -- would it still work since it's reading off the bundled source file?

Comment: Yes, the `.vue` single file components are bundled and you don't need to ship them.

Comment: @Connum althought, it's suggested to keep them, because sometimes there's issues with template compilation/generation - either of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.vue` files are source files, and should therefore be in source control all the time. When it is compiled (using vue-cli for instance), a `.js` file will come out of it and that is what the browser needs.

So yes for production environments you can remove the `.vue` files since you only need the bundled and compiled code.